# How to set charset when using dotnet ef migrations to create a database?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, mariadb

I have set my Connection string to use Character Set=utf8mb4:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "User Id=root;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=my_database;Character Set=utf8mb4;Password=password;"
  }
```

I ran `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` to create the initial migration with the database creation, but when I run `dotnet ef database update` the database is created with `latin1` charset.

Comment: Not possible? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character set specified in the DSN/connection string specifies the client character set, it will be used for conversion when sending data to and from the server.

To change the default character set of the server you have the following options:

- Specifying the character set when creating a database (or table):
  `CREATE SCHEMA myschema DEFAULT CHARSET= utf8` or `CREATE TABLE mytable (a varchar(100)) CHARSET=utf8`
- Changing the server character set for the current session: `SET session character_set_server=utf8`
- Changing the server configuration by adding (or changing) the entry `character-set-server=utf8` in your server configuration file.

`SET global character_set_server=utf8` will work too, but after a server restart it will be set to the previous (default) value.

If you create a new table (without specifying the character set) the default character set from the database/schema will be used.

Comment: Thank you. Yes as far as I can tell you'd have to at least set the default charset on the server so the database is created with it or create the db ahead of migratipns and set the charset.

Comment: When doing `CREATE TABLE`, specify the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` for that table.  (This avoids dependence on global settings that could go awry.)